# How remove active class from router-link when :to property get false value?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I use `router-link` in vue for menu.
I want make the link be enabled when the `routeName` is `specificName1` or `specificName2`.
I use a if clause in `:to` property and make links diabled and enabeld.
But when `:to` property is false, however is disabled, but has the active class.
How can I make it be disabled but with disabled class?

```js
Vue.component('customIcon', {
  template: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15.352" height="15.355" viewBox="0 0 15.352 15.355">
        <path id="Union_19" data-name="Union 19" d="M-19.5-15958.5l-7.5,7.5,7.5-7.5-7.5-7.5,7.5,7.5,7.5-7.5-7.5,7.5,7.5,7.5Z" transform="translate(27.176 15966.178)" fill="none" stroke="#bbb" stroke-width="0.5"/>
    </svg>`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      routeName: 'specificName1',
      menu: [
      {to: 'link1', name: 'name1'},
      {to: 'link2', name: 'name2'},
      {to: 'link3', name: 'name3'}
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div>
  <ul>
    <router-link
      v-for="{ to, name } in menu"
      v-slot="{ href, navigate, isActive, isExactActive }"
      :key="name"
      :to="(routeName === 'specificName1' || routeName === 'specificName2') && to"
    >
      <li :class="['nav-item', isActive && 'active', isExactActive && 'exact-active']">
        <a
          v-t="name"
          :href="href"
          @click="navigate"
        />
      </li>
    </router-link>
  </ul>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't see the outputs because your snippet had errors. But I think the problem is that you want to add a `disabled` class when the `to` parameter is not equal to the `specific` value. If this is your issue you can simply add `:class="[routeName !== 'specificName1' && routeName !== 'specificName2' ? 'disabled' : '' ]"` to your element.

Comment: The problem is `disabled` will add to the tag but not shown in style console. 
Why when `:to` has `false` value, the isActive gets `true`?

Answer (score 0):

when you are in the same URL of router-link **to** the property, the element class will be active.

for example if you are in search page, following element class will be **active**:

```
<router-link to="/search"></router-link>
```

Comment: That's true. But if you are in `/search` page and another link has `:to=false` it will have the active class too. How make `:to-false` links not get the active class?

Comment: try this.$forceUpdate() after change link.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution. Based on this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/pull/2098#issuecomment-683768041), `vue-router` doesn't provide the `disabled` attribute, so you can use `CSS` to do the trick.

I tried to simulate your situation because I couldn't see the result of your snippet. If it needs any update please let me know.

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const Name1 = {
  template: `<h1>Name1</h1>`,
}

const Name2 = {
  template: `<h1>Name2</h1>`,
}

const Name3 = {
  template: `<h1>Name3</h1>`,
}

const specificName1 = {
  template: `<h1>specificName1</h1>`,
}

const routes = [{
    path: '/name1',
    name: 'name1',
    component: Name1
  },
  {
    path: '/name2',
    name: 'name2',
    component: Name2
  },
  {
    path: '/name3',
    name: 'name3',
    component: Name3
  },
  {
    path: '/specific',
    name: 'specificName1',
    component: specificName1
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
})
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data() {
    return {
      routeName: 'specificName1',
      menu: [{
          to: 'link1',
          name: 'name1'
        },
        {
          to: 'link2',
          name: 'name2'
        },
        {
          to: 'link3',
          name: 'name3'
        },
        {
          to: 'specific',
          name: 'specificName1'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

a.router-link-active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router"></script>

<!-- App -->
<div id="app">
  <nav>
    <router-link v-for="{ to, name } in menu" :key="name" :class="{disabled: (name === 'specificName1' || name === 'specificName2')}" :to="{name: name}">{{name}}</router-link>
  </nav>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```